# Writing Tag Wiki Excerpts

Tags: discussion, tag-wikis

Just want to point out some of these guidelines and discussions from the global meta site:

- [Should tag wiki excerpts include "for issues relating to"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116752/should-tag-wiki-excerpts-include-for-issues-relating-to)
- [What's the current policy on prefixing tags wiki excerpts with tag names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107056/whats-the-current-policy-on-prefixing-tags-wiki-excerpts-with-tag-names)
- [Can we please have better tag wikis and excerpts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96331/can-we-please-have-better-tag-wikis-and-excerpts)